# App stops responding when startActivityForResults is called second time

Tags: android

Sir,I am making an chat app where I want to  pick an image and upload it on database.for this i used intent and *startActivityForResults* to open a gallery then then selects required image and finally handle the data in onActivityResults.this works well for the first time but when i perform the same operation second time app stops responding.Here is my code

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
```

and handle code in same activity:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK&& data!=null) {
            // Get the Image from data
            Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();

         UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/" + "IMG" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())).putFile(selectedImageURI);


            uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, ""+progress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    System.out.println("Upload is paused");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "You haven't failure Image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // Handle successful uploads on complete
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

there is no *logcat error* as app doesn't crashes.it just stops responding with a dialog box asking wait or stop.Please Help!!!

Comment: Don't know if this is going to help, but try to put the whole upload process into an `ASyncTask`. I guess the upload process is blocking the interaction with the app which causes it to freeze

Comment: It didn't worked even when i remove the whole uploading part i.e with empty onActivityResult